# Here Maps Api for Javascript 3.1 - Very Slow

Tags: here-api

Between Here Maps Api for Javascript version  3.1 and Here Maps Api for Javascript version 3 is a big difference.
The loading time, zooming, routes displaying is much much slower , up to 3 times.

We are usisng the default settings, but even so, on half of our computers on which we used HERE version 3 we cannot use the new version 3.1. It is not loading (cannot be used).

What can be done? I cannot afford to change all the computer to another computers of last generation.
Are there some settings which can be used to reduce the responsive time of the maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to load legacy packages and use legacy rendering engine (no tilting/rotation, only raster base layer):

**load legacy core package:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    .....
      <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core-legacy.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    .....
```

**create map with legacy rendering engine:**

```js
// assuming platform is instantiated

// Obtain the default map types from the platform object:
let defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

let map = new H.Map(
    document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
    defaultLayers.raster.normal.map,
    {
      zoom: 10,
      center: { lat: 52.5, lng: 13.4 },
      engineType: H.map.render.RenderEngine.EngineType.P2D
    });
```

**by default, fractional zoom levels are enabled in 3.1, therefore to have crisp map it is recommended to disable it:**

```js
//assuming that UI and mapevents behavior are instantiated

// disable fractional zooming for Behavior
behavior.disable(H.mapevents.Behavior.Feature.FRACTIONAL_ZOOM);

// add H.ui.ZoomControl with the disabled fractional zooming
var zoomControl = new H.ui.ZoomControl({fractionalZoom: false});
ui.addControl('zoom', zoomControl);
```

For more information check the [Migration guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/migration.html)

Comment: It works, but in 3.1 there are no traffic tiles for raster maps (normal, satellite, terrain).  Do you know how to enable them in legacy/raster mode? Thanks.

Comment: Answering myself - there is a same question solved (again) by @tomas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247014/here-maps-for-javascript-api-traffic-flow-without-webgl 
Also there is possibility to add new layer only with traffic imaginery by using `flowtile` instead of `traffictile`.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped.